# Unable to Print matching hashmap keys in Java using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, regex, hash

I am trying to iterate two hash maps and print the keys that are matching in both of them.Although both of the hash maps have got matching elements it is consistently saying "no match found".

Below posted is my code.

```
       try {

         String s = new String(data);
         String string = new String(input_bytes);
         StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s);
         StringTokenizer input_stringTokenizer = new  StringTokenizer(string);
        while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
         {

          map.put(stringTokenizer.nextToken(), stringTokenizer.nextToken());

          }
        while(input_stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
          {

          input_map.put(input_stringTokenizer.nextToken(),  
            input_stringTokenizer.nextToken());
           }}
          catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                   }}

          Iterator input1 = map.entrySet().iterator();
          Iterator input_2 = input_map.entrySet().iterator();

         while (input_2.hasNext() && input1.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry input_val1 = (Map.Entry) input1.next();
            Map.Entry input_val2 = (Map.Entry) input_2.next();
            String temp = input_val1.getKey().toString().substring(input_val1.getKey().toString().lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
           String temp_2 = input_val2.getKey().toString().substring(input_val2.getKey().toString().lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

          if(temp.equals(temp_2))
                  {

                    System.out.println("element matched");
                   }
                  else
                     {
                         System.out.println("no match found!");
                      }
                      }
```

My input files are "data" and "input_bytes"

The path in these files is the "key" and the hash is the "value" of the hashmap.

For effective matching i have trimmed the path such that it gives me only the element after the last slash.

"temp" variable in the code will print  in the following way :

```
 com.example.android.notepad_4.4.2-eng.build.20150616.1901504.apk ﹕  
 com.facebook.orca_34.0.0.22.2114.apk
 com.android.contacts_4.4.2-eng.build.20150616.1901504.apk
 com.amazon.venezia_release-13.0003.844.1C_6430003104.apk
 com.android.deskclock_3.0.04.apk
 com.google.android.apps.photos_1.0.0.943910814.apk
 apuslauncher-2.apk
 com.android.vending-v5.8.11-80381100-Android-2.3.apk
 net.sylark.apkextractor_1.0.54.apk
```

Here is how  my "data" file look like:

```
  C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\input_3\com.amazon.venezia_release-  
  13.0003.844.1C_6430003104.apk
  266796d1b8e2e016753ee3bf1b50e591
  C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\input_3\com.android.browser_4.4.2-  
  eng.build.20150616.1901504.apk
  4aa2091b0e21fc655e19d07e2ae20982
  C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\input_3\com.android.calculator2_4.4.2-  
  eng.build.20150616.1901504.apk
  85313ccbd39a43952906b70b941d321b
  C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\input_3\com.android.calendar_4.4.2-  
  eng.build.20150616.1901504.apk
  3c85cb87f2e134a4157e5f3747e4df1b
```

Here is my "input_bytes" file looks like:

```
C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\baal\com.amazon.venezia_release- 
13.0003.844.1C_6430003104.apk
266796d1b8e2e016753ee3bf1b50e591
C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\baal\com.android.browser_4.4.2-  
eng.build.20150616.1901504.apk
4aa2091b0e21fc655e19d07e2ae20982
C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\baal\com.android.calculator2_4.4.2-   
eng.build.20150616.1901504.apk
85313ccbd39a43952906b70b941d321b
C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\baal\com.android.calendar_4.4.2-   
eng.build.20150616.1901504.apk
3c85cb87f2e134a4157e5f3747e4df1b
C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\baal\com.android.camera2_2.0.002-  
eng.build.ef73894.060315_142358-704.apk
482205cda6991f89fb35311dea668013
```

If you can see there are some matches in both the files.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a much simpler way to check if they contain the same keys:

```
public void findSameKeys(Map<String, String> map1, Map<String, String> map2) {
    for (String key : map1.keySet()) {
        if (map2.containsKey(key)) {
            System.out.println("Matching key: " + key);
        }
    }
}
```

The `containsKey()` method is very useful here.